# Как понять формат времени "2015-10-04T09:53:22.8558183-04:00" на Java

Tags: java, datetime, format

что это за формат? **"2015-10-04T09:53:22.8558183-04:00"**

22.8558183 это с наносекундами?

как мне можно получить валидную дату с этой строчки?

Comment: Очень похоже на формат поля DateTime из PostgreSQL. Откуда у Вас эти данные?Да Вы правы это секунды, а после точки доли секунды указаны

Comment: это формат указания даты и времени согласно стандарту [iso 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3):

2015-10-04T09:53:22.8558183-04:00

2015-год

10-месяц

04 - ден

T разделитель времени

09 - час

53 - минута

22 - секунда

.8558183 - миллисекунда

-04:00 - Timezone со знаком (-/+) и отрезок [-12:00..+12:00]

> как мне можно получить валидную дату с этой строчки?

для решения этого вопроса, вам нужно предоставить код откуда вы взяли эти данные

для `Timestamp` можно использовать `Calendar`, если из `Postgres` тогда поменять формат данных в запросе

Comment: Мне достался этот формат в JSON, ".8558183 - миллисекунда" в некоторых местах читаю что это миллисекунда в некоторых - наносекунда.

Comment: @Pavel 855,8183 это миллисекунда 855818,3 это наносекунда

Comment: 22.8558183 секунд.